# How to set an agent{} in a shared pipeline library in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a shared pipeline library for projects using either a Docker agent or agents specified via labels. I want the agent{} section to be configurable.

In a regular Jenkinsfile for a project using Docker the agent section looks like this:

```
agent
{
    docker
    {
        label 'docker'
        image 'my-image'
    }
}
```

The agent section of projects not using Docker looks like this:

```
agent
{
    node
    {
        label 'FOO'
        label 'BAR'
    }
}
```

What is the correct syntax for the agent section of the shared pipeline lib that would yield either the first or the second agent{} examples from above?

```
// /vars/sharedPipeline.groovy
def call(body) {
    def pipelineParams= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {
        agent {
            // <---- What goes here? What is the value that pipelineParams.buildAgent should have?
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to avoid solutions that will force me to:

- manually invoke 'docker run' from within a stage
- check the label to decide what to do next

**Update:**
Based on what I have found so far it is not possible to dynamically choose between docker and non-docker agents at the top level of the pipeline. There are some workarounds available and they require specifying an agent for each individual stage or they use docker.image().inside() chains protected by some control flow constructs.

Comment: Well, you somewhere have to define the distinction if one wants to run inside a container or not, thats nothing to do with the label. I.e. you might want to use docker in a `sh` step and define the docker label to get the right node reserved, but not run inside some container. So i guess you need to have some parameter to your library function to configure that.

Comment: @DominikGebhart thank you. I want to select the agent (Docker or not) in the Jenkinsfile from which sharedPipeline will be invoked. I want to use the value from pipelineParams.buildAgent to set the agent for the entire pipeline.

Comment: I see. You might have to `if (pipelineParams.buildAgent == 'docker') { docker {[...]} else if ...`, at least thats hiddein in the library code.

Comment: @DominikGebhart Thank you I will try this.